# MacOS: remove temporary Microsoft files

Tags: excel, unix, powerpoint, macos-sierra

My situation is as follows:

`$ pwd`

`/Users/user_name/Desktop`

`$ ls`

`~$file_1.xlsx        ~$file_2.pptx       ~$file_3.pptx`

`$ rm ~$file_1.xlsx`

`rm: ~.xlsx: No such file or directory`

Best I can gather, these files were opened during a VPN connection, and the connection was closed before the file was.

Each has permissions `-rw-r--r--@`

None are visible.

`rm -rf` also doesn't work.

Any way to get rid of these?

Comment: I don't have a mac OS, so I don't know if this will work. Try finding the inode number of those files - `ls -il` then run the following command: `find . -inum <i node number of the file here> | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the inode number of those files using `ls -il`

Then run the following command:

```
find . -inum <i node number of the file here> | xargs rm -rf
```